# Display month and day in localized format

Tags: qt, localization, qt4, qt5

I need to get correct month and day format for various locales.
I have *QLable* and *QDate*, label must display month and day. I try format date by *QLocale*.

```
//Yes, I got system locale and set is as default    
QLocale::toString(date, "MMMM d");
```

But result is incorrect.

For example, "MMMM d" in German locale equal to:

> "d. MMMM"

for French is:

> "d MMMM"

How to transform "MMMM d" format to locale settings in Qt 4.8?

Thanks!

P.S. In javascript I use following code

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));
var options = {month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options));
```

Comment: It's incorrect because of the order of month and day, which is language-dependent? One way then would be to use two separate calls to toString() with "MMMM" and "d" respectively, and use tr("%1. %2", "day. month").arg(localizedDay, localizedMonth). That will require to provide translations for each language you want to support though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I used ICU library. [DateTimePatternGenerator](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1DateTimePatternGenerator.html) solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to parse `QLocale::LongFormat`:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QList<QLocale> locales;
    locales << QLocale(QLocale::English);
    locales << QLocale(QLocale::German);
    locales << QLocale(QLocale::French);
    locales << QLocale(QLocale::Russian);
    locales << QLocale(QLocale::Chinese);
    locales << QLocale(QLocale::Korean);

    foreach(QLocale locale, locales) {
        QString format = locale.dateFormat(QLocale::LongFormat);

        QRegExp rx("([^d]d(?!d)[^,;]?\\s?|M+.?){2}");
        rx.indexIn(format);
        QString localed = rx.cap(0).trimmed();

        qDebug() << locale.bcp47Name() << "\t" << localed << "\t" << locale.toString(QDateTime::currentDateTime(), localed);
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

Outputs:

```
"en-US"          "MMMM d"        "March 17"
"de-DE"          "d. MMMM"       "17. März"
"fr-FR"          "d MMMM"        "17 mars"
"ru-RU"          "d MMMM"        "17 марта"
"zh-CN"          "M月d日"        "3月17日"
"ko-KR"          "M월 d일"       "3월 17일"
```

Comment: I use similar implementation, but its not perfect.

For exemple, I use your code and add another locale

`locales << QLocale(QLocale::English);`

output is:

`"MMMM d,"        "March 17,"`
As you can see we have extra coma

Comment: I tuned the regex to exclude coma after `d`.

Comment: Using regex is quite risky decision

Comment: It is, unless you check that it works for all the languages. Otherwise you have to keep a list of formats for every language, e.g. in translations as @frank-osterfeld commented.